# Laravel testing Authentication. Failed on subsequent login attemtps with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException

Tags: laravel, testing, eloquent, phpunit, laravel-8

I'm trying to test Laravel with different users roles.

I have made 4 tests (actually, 2 tests with 2 different approach):

```php
use RefreshDatabase;

/** @test */
public function if_administrators_can_view_user_list_post()
{
    $this->seed();

    $user = User::find(1);
    $credentials = [
        'email'     => $user->email,
        'password'  => 'password'
    ];

    $response = $this->post(route('login'), $credentials);

    $this->get(route('admin.users.index'))
        ->assertStatus(200);

    $this->post(route('logout'));
}

/** @test */
public function if_users_cannot_view_user_list_post()
{
    $this->seed();

    $user = User::find(2);
    $credentials = [
        'email'     => $user->email,
        'password'  => 'password'
    ];

    $response = $this->post(route('login'), $credentials);

    $this->get(route('admin.users.index'))
        ->assertStatus(403);

    $this->post(route('logout'));
}

/** @test */
public function if_administrators_can_view_user_list_auth()
{
    $this->seed();

    $user = User::find(1);

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $user->email, 'password' => 'password'])) {
        $this->get(route('admin.users.index'))
            ->assertStatus(200);

        Auth::logout();
    } else {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
}

/** @test */
public function if_users_cannot_view_user_list_auth()
{
    $this->seed();

    $user = User::find(2);

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $user->email, 'password' => 'password'])) {
        $this->get(route('admin.users.index'))
            ->assertStatus(403);

        Auth::logout();
    } else {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

The database is seeded with 2 `users`. User `id = 1` is an administrator, and user `id = 2` is an ordinary user.

If I run each test separately, all tests are OK:

```sh
PS C:\laravel> php artisan test --filter if_administrators_can_view_user_list_post
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.

   PASS  Tests\Feature\Routes\UserRoutesTest
  ✓ if administrators can view user list post

  Tests:  1 passed
  Time:   1.51s

PS C:\laravel> php artisan test --filter if_users_cannot_view_user_list_post
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.

   PASS  Tests\Feature\Routes\UserRoutesTest
  ✓ if users cannot view user list post

  Tests:  1 passed
  Time:   1.54s

PS C:\laravel> php artisan test --filter if_administrators_can_view_user_list_auth
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.

   PASS  Tests\Feature\Routes\UserRoutesTest
  ✓ if administrators can view user list auth

  Tests:  1 passed
  Time:   1.45s

PS C:\laravel> php artisan test --filter if_users_cannot_view_user_list_auth
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.

   PASS  Tests\Feature\Routes\UserRoutesTest
  ✓ if users cannot view user list auth

  Tests:  1 passed
  Time:   1.50s
```

But, if I run all tests, the second and others failed with  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException exception:

```sh
PS C:\laravel> php artisan test 

   FAIL  Tests\Feature\Routes\UserRoutesTest
  ✓ if administrators can view user list post
  ⨯ if users cannot view user list post
  ⨯ if administrators can view user list auth
  ⨯ if users cannot view user list auth

• Tests\Feature\Routes\UserRoutesTest > if users cannot view user list post
   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException 

  No query results for model [App\Models\User] 1

  at C:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php:434
    430▕         } elseif (! is_null($result)) {
    431▕             return $result;
    432▕         }
    433▕
  ➜ 434▕         throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(
    435▕             get_class($this->model), $id
    436▕         );
    437▕     }
    438▕

  1   C:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:23
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::findOrFail()

  2   C:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1993
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), "findOrFail")

  • Tests\Feature\Routes\UserRoutesTest > if administrators can view user list auth
   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException 

  No query results for model [App\Models\User] 1

  at C:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php:434
    430▕         } elseif (! is_null($result)) {
    431▕             return $result;
    432▕         }
    433▕
  ➜ 434▕         throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(
    435▕             get_class($this->model), $id
    436▕         );
    437▕     }
    438▕

  1   C:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:23
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::findOrFail()

  2   C:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1993
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), "findOrFail")

  • Tests\Feature\Routes\UserRoutesTest > if users cannot view user list auth
   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException 

  No query results for model [App\Models\User] 1

  at C:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php:434
    430▕         } elseif (! is_null($result)) {
    431▕             return $result;
    432▕         }
    433▕
  ➜ 434▕         throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(
    435▕             get_class($this->model), $id
    436▕         );
    437▕     }
    438▕

  1   C:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:23
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::findOrFail()

  2   C:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1993
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), "findOrFail")


  Tests:  3 failed, 1 passed
  Time:   1.84s
```

Does anyone has any clue to this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's tackle some small details first:

1. Never write a test that asserts 2 different (or more) behaviors in the same test. A test should only test 1 thing. `if_administrators_can_view_user_list_auth`, should be `user_list_vieable_by_administrator` or `user_list_vieable_when_user_is_logged_in_as_administrator` or anything similar. You have to create the inverse too, `user_list_not_vieable_when_user_is_not_admin` and in this one you can test all possible user's types that are not administrator type.
2. Never write a test name as a conditional (at least using `if`). For example, if you want to test if a user can post a message in an X app, write the test as `test_user_can_create_post_when_logged_in` instead of `if_user_is_logged_in_create_post` or anything similar. This is sort of a convention. Read about User Stories and Acceptance Criteria, there is a way of writing this, you should follow Acceptance Criteria writing convention.
3. Instead of blindly seeding, my personal recommendation is to **ONLY HAVE IN YOUR DATABASE** what you are going to test, it doesn't matter if you create entries for a model you will never use, maybe that could alter something in your system and you are not taking that into account.

   - Let's say the user does not need to have an `Avatar` uploaded when they Post something, but your code is wrong and you **REQUIRE** an avatar. Because you are bindly seeding anything (even stuff that you should not require for your test), your test could pass, but behind scenes, you required it for it to work, do you follow me ?
4. Remember you can use [`dataProvider`s](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html#dataprovider) on PHPUnit to feed different data to your test, like point number 2 I mentioned here. Instead of creating a lot of different types of users, you can feed them and run a single test on each of the types, so when any fails, you can see which one failed, and also your test does not get bloated with setup data.
5. Never use `route` helper when testing. For example, if you desired route is `POST /user/post` and the name is `user.post.store`, you will do `$this->post(route('user.post.store'), [...]);`, but what if `user.post.store` URL is like `/asd/123/bad/url-5555` ? You are not testing that you access a desired URL and does what you want. So you must test everything, even if you have to type it like a robot, you **MUST** test everything and not rely on anything like that, because it is a feature test, so you are testing EVERYTHING you can. If you could change frameworks and the code is still the same, it should still be working (let's say you don't use `route` helper), it should still be accessible by your desired URL, etc. Don't use helpers except for asserting stuff.

So, to help you a little more, you should not *bindly* seed everything. Remember you can use `$this->seed(SeederName::class);`, if you use `->seed();` it will use default seeder. You can even pass an array with more than 1 seeder.

---

I am now going to rewrite your tests so you can see what can be done better:

```php
/** @test */
public function user_list_vieable_when_user_is_logged_in_as_administrator()
{
    /** @var User $user Remember this user is an admin, set up that */
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)
        ->get('/admin/users');

    $response->assertOk();
}
```

That test is exactly the same as `if_administrators_can_view_user_list_post`, but see that:

- I did not blindly seed anything, just what I needed. I may need to factory something more to make that user an admin but this is an example, you know what to set up to make that happen.
- I did not literally login, but I "simulated" login in. If you want to simulate being logged in, you have to use [`$this->actingAs($model, 'guard');`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication), you can even specify which guard to use as the second parameter.
- You don't need to log out, as the next test will be "reseted" so you will have no session. Fresh like a new test.
- You can also use some "synonyms", for example `assertOk()` is exactly the same as `->assertStatus(200)`, you can use `->assertSuccessful()` and that would be `status >= 200 && status < 300`. But this is really personal. See all the [available asserts](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#response-assertions) as there are more about this.

Now let's continue with the other ones:

```php
/** @test */
public function user_list_forbidden_when_user_is_not_admin()
{
    /** @var User $user Remember this user is not an admin, set up that */
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)
        ->get('/admin/users');

    $response->assertForbidden();
}
```

Again, I just created the user with needed permissions, and tested against the desired route, then asserted it was forbidden. I would personally return `401` (*unauthorized*) as `403` is more special, but it is fairly similar.

In this case, you could use `dataProvider` as I mentioned before and test each type of user, so you are 100% sure that it will be forbidden for any user that is not an admin or any type you want.

Let's quickly "simulate" it as I have no idea about your schema. Let's say that we have a `role` column in your `User` table, so you could do this:

```php
/**
 * @test
 * @dataProvider
 */
public function user_list_forbidden_when_user_is_not_admin(string $type)
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = User::factory()->$type()->create();

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)
        ->get('/admin/users');

    $response->assertForbidden();
}

public function common_user_types_data_provider()
{
    return [
        'Normal' => ['normal'],
        'Moderator' => ['moderator'],
        'Editor' => ['editor'],
        'Vip' => ['vip']
    ];
}
```

I have taken advantage of [`states`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-states), but you can send anything you need, except data or classes that must be run **AFTER** the framework is ready. `dataProvider`s run **BEFORE** the framework is ready, so you cannot use anything about it.

Following your tests order, I am not 100% sure what you wanted to test in `if_administrators_can_view_user_list_auth` and `if_users_cannot_view_user_list_auth`, but I am assuming you wanted to test something similar to the previous tests, but also what happens if the user is not logged in. So in the previous test we did not test what happens when a user is not even logged in, until that test we always assumed the user was logged in with a role, now let's test when a user is not even logged in:

```php
/** @test */
public function guest_user_should_get_redirected_to_login_when_viewing_admin_users_dashboard()
{
    // As we are guests, we directly access the URL, we do not need to do anything else
    $response = $this->get('/admin/users');

    $response->assertRedirect('/login');
}
```

See the test naming I have used, you should always use `should` instead of `must`, `when` instead of `if`.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, @matiaslauriti. I just started with testing on Laravel, so, your insight are very helpful. I made all changes to keep close to your approach, and it seems use of actingAs($user) does not work. Both tests failed with same Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException. Even if I run tests separately.

Comment: `actingAs` will not throw that error, that error is coming from somewhere else, if you are still using `seeders`, there is the problem. Can you update your question with an image of the error ? Check that the stack trace is viewable so I can see where is it coming from.

Comment: Any news on this ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have test cases like OP. 2 similar tests with diffrent account role to check if each role can/can't see some Text. In browser or running single test case, it's successful, but if I run the test file (2 test cases together, or mayby sequent), the second case will failed because the first account keep logging in. Do you have any idea for this? Even  I devide 2 test cases into 2 files, nothing changes.

Comment: @lehien I have no idea. I recommend you post this as a question with all the information and the things you have tried out, and remember to use [tag:laravel] and [tag:phpunit] tags so I can see it and try to help you